# NSUnknownKeyException error because of UIImageView and UITextField

Tags: swift

I am getting NSUnknownKeyException error:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key" for this line of code: @IBOutlet weak var UsernameTextField: UITextField!.

However, I did check that there is no extra referencing outlet that is not needed.

[image: Referencing outlet]

Also this code only throws error if I connect the code with the UITextField in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

did you rename @IBOutlet weak var UsernameTextField: UITextField! to @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField! (lower case u) in your code file? That will cause this error. Its case sensitive.

Comment: No I didn't. The names are exactly the same. Any other possible case that will lead to this issue?